# Replace text in a span that also contains other DOM elements

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have a code like this and I need to remove the `&#8203;` characters that are inserted automatically by the code that I have no control over (generated by SharePoint). They ruin the layout by inserting extra empty lines:

```
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField" class="ms-rtestate-field" style="display:inline" aria-labelledby="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_label">
    &#8203;&#8203;&#8203;
        <span>                            &#8203;
          <div class="cg-division-intro-outer">
            <div class="cg-division-intro-inner">
                <div class="cg-division-intro-header">
                    <h1>Division Intro</h1>
                </div>

... etc
```

Notice that the `&#8203;` entities are inserted as bare text, not wrapped into any element, so I cannot target them directly.

Here is what I tried:

1. Using `visibility: hidden` on the element containing the garbage and visibility: visible on my code. Has no effect.
2. Reducing `font-size` on the parent element containing the garbage to 0px and restoring the font-size on other elements. Has no effect.
3. Obtaining the `innerHTML` of the parent element, doing the `.replace()` and reinserting HTML back into the page - but then all the nodes will be lost/recreated, which means any attached listeners may be lost.
4. Tried using :not but didn't come up with a solution that works.

Here is the white bar created by those `&#8203;`s:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/27vymq1t/)

JS

use `childNodes` and change its value by `nodeValue`

```
var d = document.getElementById('div1').childNodes[0];
d.nodeValue = "new text"; // change value

// if you want to remove the element
d.parentElement.removeChild(d)
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
  some texts
  <div id="div2">
    other elements
    <div>hkeqvdkqbdklq</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @K48 sorry forget to link, now added! Thanks :)